# Can Adium or Thunderbird-Chat fetch history of conversations that are received and sent when it is closed?

Tags: thunderbird, adium

I am using [`Adium` (https://adium.im) or [Thunderbird-chat](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/instant-messaging-and-chat)] to connect to my google hangouts account for instant messaging.

=> I have realised that on its talk history, `Adium` only shows the messages that are received when it is running. While it is closed, if I received a message it won't show up.

=> On Thunderbird, on each restart of the app its all conversations are cleaned, so I cannot see any previous message:
[image]

---

**[Q]** Can `Adium` or `Thunderbird` fetch the complete history of conversations that are received and sent when it is closed?